# Yoast meta Description auto generated not working

Tags: wordpress, seo

I am using Yoast for my website SEO.
I have added `%%excerpt%%` for my meta description, but auto generated is not working. I want to add my post content for my meta description.

Anyone knows solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

This was a bug and is already fixed. Update your plugin and you can report bugs here: https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/